# Why tooltip position absolute does not apply using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to fix position absolute issue for charjs tooltip but failed to fix it. I have tried a lot about it and found some relevant threads and I tried to implement on my script but unfortunately not working. May be I am doing in wrong way.

I have this [**chart**](https://jsfiddle.net/full_stack_dev/9vag73qd/1/) which has tool-tip and it is cutting from top side. I can say from all side because when it show from bottom side then it's also cutting.

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {

        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return  data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + ' has sold' ;
        },
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return 'On ' + data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']] ;
        }
    },
    backgroundColor: '#0C1330',
    titleFontSize: 13,
    titleFontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    titleMarginBottom:10,
    bodyFontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    bodyFontSize: 14,
    bodySpacing:4,
    yPadding: 5,
    xPadding: 5,
    footerMarginBottom: 5,
    displayColors: false,
    yAlign: 'bottom'
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that the box you are trying to display is cut because off the canvas size. So when the box is shown, it is going outside the canvas, and therefore it is not display. Have you tried making the canvas bigger ?

Comment: @Flubssen actually I need to show four charts in single row so I can't resize it

Comment: Then you need to make the box smaller so it fits within the canvas size. because element that is rederet inside a canvas, can't be displayed outside of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try by reducing the font and padding sizes as below. 
IF this works for you :

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {

        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return  data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + ' has sold' ;
        },
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return 'On ' + data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']] ;
        }
    },
    backgroundColor: '#0C1330',
    titleFontSize: 10,
    titleFontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    titleMarginBottom:1,
    bodyFontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    bodyFontSize: 11,
    bodySpacing:1,
    yPadding: 2,
    xPadding: 2,
    footerMarginBottom: 2,
    displayColors: false,
    yAlign: 'bottom'
}
```

Link : https://jsfiddle.net/p5gvLu6h/